# Java spring boot updating entity results in timeout and bugged entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a Java/Spring application where I use websockets to synchronize data. I have multiple socket methods where I update certain entities. I also have an update method where I update an entity depending on the received data, like: 
when I get field x I only update field x.

However, when I try to update a certain field, it crashes after a while with a `PessimisticLockException` where the timeout is exceeded. Increasing the timeout in `phpyMyAdmin` does not work because it will just try longer before crashing again.

Now the weird part is that after the application has crashed, the entity seems bugged in `phpMyAdmin` cause I can't update the specific field myself because I also get a timeout here. However, when I create a new entity in the database and update the field in phpMyAdmin myself before using the websocket, it does work and does not crash. I tried deleting and creating the database multiple times but always the same bug.

Does anyone else have experience with this issue and how can I resolve it? If possible, I could show the exact experience over **Teamviewer** etc. to get a better understanding of the problem. I checked the update query with trace debug but the data send is nothing weird.

Websocket method code:

```
@MessageMapping("/entity/update/{bordId}")
@SendTo("/entity/updated/{bordId}")
public Pair<BordRowItem, Integer> updateBordRowItem(String message) {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(message);

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    BordRowItem item;
    ArrayList<BordRowItemEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();

    Optional<BordRowItem> optionalBordRowItem = bordRowItemRepository.findById(object.getInt("id"));

    if(!optionalBordRowItem.isPresent()) {
        return null;
    }

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    item = optionalBordRowItem.get();

    if(object.has("description")) {
            String msg = (item.getDescription() != null && !item.getDescription().isEmpty()) ? " van '" + item.getDescription() + "'" : "";

        BordRowItemEvent event = new BordRowItemEvent("changed" + msg + " to '" + object.getString("description") + "'");
        event.setBordRowItem(item);
        events.add(event);

        item.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
    }

    for(BordRowItemEvent event : events) {
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(event) && !entityManager.contains(event)) {
            entityManager.persist(event);
            entityManager.flush();
        }
    }

    bordRowItemRepository.save(item);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    entityManager.close();
    return new Pair<>(item, item.getBordRow().getId());
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.dao.PessimisticLockingFailureException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:292) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:254) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:537) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:744) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:712) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:619) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:372) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.project.project.project.controller.WebSocketController.updateBordRowItem(WebSocketController.java:348) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:565) [spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:511) [spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:94) [spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:520) [spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:454) [spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:144) [spring-messaging-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$3.convert(MySQLDialect.java:536) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3392) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3265) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3666) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1358) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:436) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3235) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2403) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:533) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:123) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you looked into why you are getting a ```PessimisticLockException```? Can you share the piece of code the update the field?

Comment: @D.Lawrence It has something to do with not being able to execute the statement. I added the code and the error message, hope this helps.